# Subgradient of the spectral norm

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms, subgradient, spectral-norm, non-smooth-analysis

I am working on developing a numerical algorithm that needs to use a subgradient of $\|\cdot\|_2$ (matrix norm) at each iteration. According to [Characterization of the Subdifferential of Some Matrix Norms](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(92)90407-2) by G.A. Watson, the subdifferential of $\|A\|$ is given by

$$ \partial \|A\| := \left\{ G \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} : \|B\| \geq \|A\| + \mbox{tr} \left( (B−A)^\top G \right), \forall B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \right\} $$

For the $\|\cdot\|_2$ of vector norm, I know that we can choose a subgradient

$$ g_n \in \partial \|\cdot\|_2(x_n) = \frac{x_n}{\|x_n\|_2},~  (x_n \neq 0) $$

at each iteration. How should I choose a subgradient for my case? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3105044/339790)

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3076947/339790)

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4321447/339790)

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4232319/339790)

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2795443/339790)

Comment: Yes, I mean the spectral norm. Is that possible? If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the links above?

Comment: Currently working on it

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2321877/339790)